# Making graphic of flashing lights

Tags: graphics, animation

The following gif is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz), lights flashing at frequencies $f=0.5 Hz$, $f=1.0 Hz$, $f=2.0 Hz$

[image]

How to make this graphic by using *Mathematica*?

I tried first few steps:

```
blackdisk = Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 60]
graydisk = Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 60]
```

Comment: Have you seen `RunScheduledTask`?

Comment: I have to admit I don't really like that this question is "how do I recreate this animation?" You probably have a more fundamental issue, such as "how do I evaluate an expression every nth second." The question should be about what you don't know, there's no point in creating a project around it and asking people to complete that project.

Comment: Perhaps [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) + [`UpdateInterval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpdateInterval.html) would be of use.

Comment: @ChipHurst Perhaps in practice, but conceptually it's not very good because `UpdateInterval` only promises to update "at least" every t seconds. That's why I recommended `RunScheduledTask`, which is exact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dynamic[
 t = Clock[{1/3, 8, 1/3}, 2];
 Graphics[{
   {GrayLevel[0.5 Boole[Mod[t, 8] == 0]], Disk[{0, 1}, 0.2]},
   {GrayLevel[0.5 Boole[Mod[t, 4] == 0]], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.2]},
   {GrayLevel[0.5 Boole[Mod[t, 2] == 0]], Disk[{0, -1}, 0.2]}
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. can you add `Epilog` on the right side?

Comment: @vito, like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/l2Sq4GG9IJXDVTsdO/giphy.gif)?

Comment: @JasonB  yes, like this

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best way to get an actually smoothly timed graphic is to make a gif..

```
blackdisk = Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 60]
graydisk = 
 Graphics[{Black, Disk[], GrayLevel[.7], Disk[{0, 0}, .9]}, 
  ImageSize -> 60]
Export["test.gif",
 Table[Column[
   Table[Blend[{blackdisk, graydisk}, 
     N@Abs@Sin[n t]], {n, {1, 2, 4}}]], {t, 0, Pi, Pi/20}], 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 1/20]
```

[image]

Incidentally, `Blend` balks at exact parameter values for no evident readson:

```
Blend[{blackdisk, graydisk}, Sin[Pi/20]]
```

> Sin[[Pi]/20] should be a real number or a list of non-negative 
>   numbers